# Pact consumer test is shown in test explorer but does not run .NET

Tags: .net, xunit, pact, pact-net

I am using PactNet.

I wrote a consumer test identical to this example on the github repo: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net

```
using System.Net;
using PactNet;
using PactNet.Matchers;
using Xunit;

public class SomethingApiConsumerTests
{
    private readonly IPactBuilderV4 pactBuilder;

    public SomethingApiConsumerTests()
    {
        // Use default pact directory ..\..\pacts and default log
        // directory ..\..\logs
        var pact = Pact.V4("Something API Consumer", "Something API", new PactConfig());

        // or specify custom log and pact directories
        pact = Pact.V4("Something API Consumer", "Something API", new PactConfig
        {
            PactDir = $"{Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}pacts"
        });

        // Initialize Rust backend
        this.pactBuilder = pact.WithHttpInteractions();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetSomething_WhenTheTesterSomethingExists_ReturnsTheSomething()
    {
        // Arrange
        this.pactBuilder
            .UponReceiving("A GET request to retrieve the something")
                .Given("There is a something with id 'tester'")
                .WithRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/somethings/tester")
                .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .WillRespond()
                .WithStatus(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .WithJsonBody(new
                {
                    id = "tester",
                    firstName = "Totally",
                    lastName = "Awesome"
                });

        await this.pactBuilder.VerifyAsync(async ctx =>
        {
            // Act
            var client = new SomethingApiClient(ctx.MockServerUri);
            var something = await client.GetSomething("tester");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal("tester", something.Id);
        });
    }
}
```

I installed XUnit and the required NuGet packages, however the test does not run.

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to run the test is usually an indicator that the specific runner for that framework is not installed. Assuming we are talking about Visual Studio, make sure that you do have `xunit.runner.visualstudio` installed.

[image: Xunit runner dependency]

If that doesn't help check out the output from running the tests. It should indicate problems while trying to execute them.